# Firebase Auth not saving current user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, stream-builder

In my app I'm trying to perform a simple login/signup operation.

I have a `StreamBuilder` that returns a Login Screen if there is no user, and a home screen if a user is logged in:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            Widget widget;
            switch (snapshot.data) {
              case (null):
                widget = SignIn();
                break;
              default:
                widget = Home();
            }

            return AnimatedSwitcher(
          child: widget,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
            return ScaleTransition(child: child, scale: animation);
          },
        );
          }),
```

The code works perfectly as shown below:

[image: Simple Login]

But when a user is already signed in, and I close and reopen the app, the login page shows briefly before it redirects to the home page.

The same happens when I click on hot restart:

[image: Hot Restart]

In the image above, I was already signed in, then I clicked hot reload and the login screen showed briefly before I was redirected to the home screen.

The same happens when the internet is turned off, and there is no animated switcher.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ConnectionState`:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
 return Container();
}
```

You can replace Container with a SplashScreen/Loading Screen

Comment: This makes so much sense! Your code doesn't work though, but I tweaked my code to match it and it does. The reason why there was an issue when restarted is because the snapshot's connection state was on "ConnectionState.waiting". So by adding a return statement to the if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting), I fixed the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Yup always use connectionstate, much better